# Can't add a geoJson layer to my Open Layers map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Using Open Layers and leaflet-sidebar-v2, I've added the sidebar to my map, this works. However, I also need to add another layer to my map, this layer will outline each country. I have the coordinates stored in a 'borders.json' file. I'm attempting to use D3.json to to import the border coordinates and then L.geoJson to add the new layer to my map.

I'm currently getting the following error message:

`Uncaught TypeError: t.getLayerStatesArray is not a function`

Here is the relevant part of my code..

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    }),
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([7, 51.2], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"),
    zoom: 3,
  }),
});

var sidebar = new ol.control.Sidebar({
  element: "sidebar",
  position: "left",
});
map.addControl(sidebar);

d3.json(("borders.json"), function (json){
    function style(feature) {
        return {
            fillColor: "transparent",
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 0.4,
            color: 'grey',
            fillOpacity: 0.3
        }
    }

    geojson = L.geoJson(json, {
      style: style,
    }).addTo(map);
})
```

I think I might be adding the geojson layer to my map incorrectly, but I can't figure out what is wrong. I've spent quite a bit of time playing with it, but no luck.

Any helps is appreciated.

Cheers,
Beat

Comment: Using d3 with OpenLayers is quite involved, see https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/d3.html.  Consider using a simple OpenLayers vector layer for GeoJSON https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/vector-label-decluttering.html or TopoJSON https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/topojson.html instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be hard to tell what the problem is without knowing other possible relevant parts of your code. I'd start by checking that the contents of `borders.json` follows [valid GeoJSON format](https://geojson.org/).

---

This is likely unrelated to your question, but is there a reason that you've declared `style` as a function like `function style(feature) { ... }`?

[It looks like](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) the `style` attribute of `L.geoJson` accepts an object rather than a function.